# SIMD Linear Search Slower than Unrolled Loop

Tags: c++, performance, search, sse, simd

I'm working on an application for which a highly optimized linear search will make a big difference in the overall performance, and I've been tasked with improving performance as much as I can.

I'm running my search on a vector of 10,000 elements that is bounded by sentinel values at the end, I run the linear search at some constant distance from the target element and measure the time it took to find the element. I choose the target elements randomly from the set of elements what are after that constant distance from the beginning of the array to allow for the beginning of the search. I'm measuring the performance using [Google's benchmark framework](http://github.com/google/benchmark/).

The results that I've collected surprise me. I expected that at some point SIMD would beat an unrolled loop for performance, but the gap between the two appears to be growing as the distance needed to travel the array grows. Additionally, I'm not sure why the loop that has been unrolled 8 times runs faster on shorter distances than the loop unrolled 32 times.

```
Benchmark                              Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/2             86 ns         86 ns    7699241
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/4            103 ns        103 ns    6797378
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/16           650 ns        650 ns    1079095
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/64          1365 ns       1365 ns     514196
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/256         3558 ns       3558 ns     196519
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/1024       12358 ns      12358 ns      56635
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/4096       47341 ns      47341 ns      14780
BM_Search<linUnroll<8>>/8192       95029 ns      95030 ns       7367
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/2           131 ns        131 ns    5337221
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/4           131 ns        131 ns    5329296
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/16          291 ns        291 ns    2404646
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/64          836 ns        836 ns     831093
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/256        2776 ns       2776 ns     252901
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/1024      10962 ns      10962 ns      63828
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/4096      41312 ns      41312 ns      16941
BM_Search<linUnroll<32>>/8192      83303 ns      83304 ns       8401
BM_Search<linSIMD>/2                 163 ns        163 ns    4304086
BM_Search<linSIMD>/4                 208 ns        208 ns    3354716
BM_Search<linSIMD>/16                366 ns        366 ns    1912122
BM_Search<linSIMD>/64                871 ns        871 ns     803854
BM_Search<linSIMD>/256              3333 ns       3334 ns     210159
BM_Search<linSIMD>/1024            11262 ns      11262 ns      62157
BM_Search<linSIMD>/4096            42656 ns      42656 ns      16413
BM_Search<linSIMD>/8192            87824 ns      87824 ns       7970
```

I'm running on an i5-4570, and I've complied with clang 5.0.0. quick-bench doesn't have AVX, and clang doesn't fully unroll in version 3.8, but it should be runnable. I tried unrolling the SIMD also, as well as going to AVX256 instructions, but both made the performance worse. Why is it that the unrolled loop is so much faster? Why is it that the loop with more unrolling performs so dramatically worse than the loop with less unrolling?

The classic diagnosis for SIMD is that you're not doing enough work in SIMD, but I think I'm doing enough work here.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <immintrin.h>
typedef int V;
typedef std::vector<V> vi;

long linSIMD(const vi& arr, const long guessIx, const V x) {
  using v4 = V __attribute__ ((vector_size (4*4)));
  using dv2 = int64_t __attribute__ ((vector_size (4*4)));
  constexpr int roll = 4;
  constexpr union {
    int32_t i32[2];
    int64_t i64;
  } skip = {-2,-2};
  v4 xVec = {x,x,x,x};
  for (int i = guessIx;; i += roll) {
    v4 arrVec;
    for (long j = 0; j < 4; j++) arrVec[j] = arr[i+j];
    union {
        v4 i32;
        dv2 i64;
    } cmpVec = {arrVec < xVec};
    v4 cmpVec2 = {cmpVec.i32[3], cmpVec.i32[2], cmpVec.i32[1],cmpVec.i32[0]};
    cmpVec.i32 += cmpVec2;
    if (cmpVec.i64[0] == skip.i64) continue;
    return i - cmpVec.i32[0] - cmpVec.i32[1];
  }
}

long linUnroll32(const vi& arr, const long guessIx, const V x) {
  constexpr int roll = 32;
  for (long i = guessIx;; i += roll)
    for (long j = 0; j < roll; j++)
        if (arr[i+j] >= x) return i+j;
}
```

http://quick-bench.com/_x_v_WXLWtwvvLsObNlIxjXxS_g
https://godbolt.org/g/Wyx2pS

Comment: Do you have to use cryptic-SIMD like that? The only way I can interpret what's going on is through the disassembly

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/4AaAYN  You seem to be doing a LOT of work to set things up in a certain way versus just doing a linear search through memory, which is about as cache friendly as it gets.

Comment: @harold I just linked to it

Comment: @eyepatch: Well, the SSE variant looks to be mostly overhead here. There is a single four-element comparison instruction followed by a transition to the integer unit, along with a shuffle/add to get the information out plus a potentially unaligned load. I suppose you've ruled out the option of an alternate data structure to speed up the search?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't look at cmpVec immediately after the comparison to continue if you don't get a match.   That should be the case you're optimizing for, because if you're likely to find a match, you're not doing that much work to begin with.   having to build a new data structure to see that you didn't get a match seems bad.

Comment: @xaxxon: It is overhead to get the data out of the SIMD unit for the branch test, and frankly rather expensive. Something along the line of a `PCMPGTD` followed by a `PMOVMSKB` ought to do the job faster though.

Comment: Here are you some benchmarks: http://quick-bench.com/lkdHZ1Nxc1p7qfG7o3bHkLe-Bcc

Comment: @harold http://quick-bench.com! This is *exactly* what I was looking for earlier today! I didn't know that existed. Thank you so much for posting that comment. This may change my life in much the same way that http://gcc.godbolt.com changed my life.

Comment: @CodyGray actually it was OP who made me aware of it, so I cannot claim credit here. Looks useful though so I'm glad I saw this question

Comment: @xaxxon I tried comparing both parts immediately and even flipping the equations to get vptest directly, but I measured and found they were slower.

Comment: @harold That seems like some interesting work. You might want to post an answer with your results. I'll see what progress I can make with the inspiration.
The reason for the using the vector code instead of using the vector instructions directly is to if the compiler can see better ways than I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could do (see results on [quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/1Un8bZJrTvo6TZxA9Bf3q2isZJ4)) was this,

```
int linSIMD4(const vi& arr, const int guessIx, const int x) {
  auto vecX = _mm_set1_epi32(x - 1);
  const int *ptr = arr.data();
  int i = guessIx;
  // unaligned start
  int misalignment = (uintptr_t)(ptr + i) & 15;
  auto arrVec = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(ptr + i));
  auto cmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(arrVec, vecX);
  int mask = _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(cmp));
  if (mask)
    return i + __builtin_ctz(mask);
  // continue with aligned part
  i += (16 - misalignment) / 4;
  for (; ; i += 16) {
    auto av0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(ptr + i));
    auto av1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(ptr + i + 4));
    auto av2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(ptr + i + 8));
    auto av3 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(ptr + i + 12));
    auto cmp0 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(av0, vecX);
    auto cmp1 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(av1, vecX);
    auto cmp2 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(av2, vecX);
    auto cmp3 = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(av3, vecX);
    auto cmp = _mm_packs_epi16(_mm_packs_epi32(cmp0, cmp1), _mm_packs_epi32(cmp2, cmp3));
    int mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp);
    if (mask)
      return i + __builtin_ctz(mask);
  }
}
```

Which is basically what geza described, but I added a special first iteration in order to align the data for the main loop. Loads that cross cache line boundaries (or page boundaries) are slower, this gets rid them. The overhead isn't worth it for small distances (with not enough slow loads), on the other hand it should be faster again for tiny distances (less than 4).

I've also tried flipping the condition (`linSIMD5`), using `(a >= b) = !(b > a)`, with non-destructive AVX encoding that would allow merging the `vcmpgtd` and the load (reducing µops in the fused domain), but quick-bench doesn't do AVX so just ignore the result and try it yourself.

There's an AVX2 version at the bottom, I haven't tried or benchmarked it. It doesn't use the load/compare-merging trick (which may or may not help) but it would be easy to adapt.

Comment: I ran linSIMD5, and I found it to be slightly worse. ptest also makes things worse. It can help to replace the unaligned SIMD batch with an unrolled loop. You lose a few ns on the 4-16 range, but gain more on the 0-4 range. There's a bug in your AVX code. the 256-bit packs does A lane, B lane, A lane, B lane. It can be fixed by permuting with this vector: (7,3,6,2,5,1,4,0) (in reverse order like the constructor)

Comment: @eyepatch the AVX code already undoes the weird implicit shuffle from the lanes, of course it might be wrong (if `reorder` is wrong) but I don't think any permute should be be necessary (it could be done with a shuffle too but it's an annoying shuffle)

Comment: I ran it on some test cases, and it returned the wrong result. It got into a state of 0xfffffeff00 or something like that where the correct result was something like i+12, but the returned result was i+8. Because of the way that the lanes are interleaved, it didn't seem possible to do it with the array like you did, although if you could, that would likely be faster. Since 0xffffffff00 and 0xfffffeff00 return the same ctz, it seems trivially impossible. Notation of interleaving is 0..f, then 00..ff.
0,1,2,3,8,9,a,b,00,11,22,33,88,99,aa,bb,4,5,6,7,c,d,e,f,44,55,66,77,cc,dd,ee,ff

Comment: @eyepatch ok yes I suppose it wouldn't necessarily find the *first* item, that's annoying.. well nevermind that idea then

Answer (score 1):

Use larger batches in the loop in the SIMD case.

For example, use compare on 4 SIMD registers, then put the resulting 16 compare result into one SIMD register. Then put a branch on this (and break from loop, if a match found). This way, you will have:

1. less branches
2. more possible parallelisation opportunity for compiler & CPU

After you break from loop, you need to find the index of the match among the 16 possible entries. You can do it with SIMD or whatever method you prefer.

This way should be faster than your current implementation (for large arrays).

Comment: I discussed that I unrolled the SIMD twice, but I'll go build a benchmark and measure.

Comment: You need to alter the branch as well, it is important (so the solution is not just copy-paste the loop twice). I recommend to use at least 4 input registers, so 16 numbers can be processed in a loop.

Comment: @eyepatch: check out harold's linSIMD3, basically it is an implementation of my recommendation. This quick-bench.com is awesome :)